# error while executing select query in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I'm using hadoop 1.1.2 , hbase 0.94.8 and hive 0.14 .
I'am trying to create a table in hbase using hive and load data in it later by insert overwrite .

for the moment I was able to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table_emp(id int, name string, role string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:name,cf1:role")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp");
```

and load data into another table that I will overwrite it into the hbase table :

```
hive> create table testemp(id int, name string, role string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t';
hive> load data local inpath '/home/user/sample.txt' into table testemp;
```

but when I try `select * from testemp;` to verify that the data was loaded successfully I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.unset(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.pushFilters(HiveInputFormat.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.initialize(FetchTask.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1067)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

could someone help me please ! thank you

Comment: Have you changed Hadoop package versions since the last time Hive was compiled?

Comment: I didn't change anything

Comment: So, nothing concrete, but despite the 0.14 release notes there seems to be at least anecdotal evidence Hive 0.14 isn't 100% compatible with Hadoop 1.1.2 just yet (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842004/issue-in-apache-hive-0-14-running-dml-queries).  I have never tried to operate Hive with Hadoop 1.x myself.

Comment: I changed to hive 0.13 and nothing works I get this error even when I tried to visualise the tables (>show tables;) :(

Comment: Unfortunately, this may be an issue specific to Hadoop 1.x then, of which I have no firsthand experience.  I'm guessing it can work with Hadoop 1.x, but perhaps just not out-of-the-box in every circumstance.

Comment: this could be a version compatibility problem or a configuration issue I just can't figure it out :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe you will have to upgrade Hadoop to at least 1.2.0.

It appears that Hive is trying to access the `unset` method of the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf` class.  In looking at the [API documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html) for that class in Hadoop 1.1.2, you can see that method does not exist.

The first release from the 1.x series in which that method gets implemented is 1.2.0 (see the [API documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html) for the same class).  Note that the method actually gets inherited from the `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` class.

Comment: thank you soo much this works for me it was a version compatibility problem :)

Comment: @YosrAbdellatif I'm glad it worked out.  It was a subtle issue to track down, to be sure, since the documentation does mention compatibility with Hadoop "1.x.y".  I guess x >= 2.  :)

Comment: @ rchang now I get another error while executing insert overwrite table hbase_table_emp select * from testemp;
I get this error: [[[[[ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cliffc/high_scale_lib/Counter]]]]] problem compatibility again?

Comment: @YosrAbdellatif Did you build HBase locally with Maven?  The missing class seems to be from `com.github.stephenc.high-scale-lib`, which is listed as a dependency in HBase's `pom.xml` file.  I'd recommend checking your library directory to see if `high-scale-lib-x.x.x.jar` (where x.x.x is some version number) is present.

Comment: @ rchang yes high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar does exist in /hbase/lib and I'm just running those queries in hive shell what maven got to do with this?

Comment: @YosrAbdellatif I was suspecting that the `high-scale-lib` jar file was possibly missing - if HBase was built locally (as opposed to just being installed as part of a CDH/HDP distribution, for example), it's possible that transitive dependencies might be missed.  Since you've verified that it exists, the other immediate caveat that occurs to me would be to make sure that Hive's runtime classpath includes the HBase libs.  Hive/HBase integration is discussed at this blog post (maybe it can help you?): http://hortonworks.com/blog/hbase-via-hive-part-1/

Comment: I'm not using a hadoop distibution I just installed each one separately and I tried to execute queries using hive and I didn't set HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH I just copied some jars from hbase/lib to hive/lib that's all ! should I set it?