# select query errored out in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using    `Hadoop - 1.0.4 & Hive - 1.2.1.`

I am facing issue with select query in hive `CLI`. snippet of error log attached. Please help me resolving the issue.

[image]

Comment: this is version issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070003/error-while-executing-select-query-in-hive

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nirmal. Its resolved after upgrading hadoop version to 2.6.0